# Is it possible to load HTML into a jTable?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable, jframe

Is it possible to load HTML into a Java component? For example, if I have HTML - perhaps a table (formatted with cell colors - can I load it into a jTable?

Comment: Too much going on with this question: HTML, JSON, CSS, JTable.    What do you want to do?  It sounds like you want to take in HTML and CSS, parse it, and convert that to a JTable/Swing equivalent.  So you have to get a parser and write the code to map <table> to JTable and translate CSS to Swing style elements.  Is that it?

Comment: I need to load into a jTable a few rows (one column only) and depends on the line parameters will be painted one color or another. But I've been reading as examples of dynamically edit the rows and I just do not understand or know how to integrate it in my project, could you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JTables aren't flexible as HTML tables. Cells can't span multiple rows or multiple columns.

Instead of this you can use JTextPane and use HTMLEditor.

You need to set content tpye to text/html and editable to false.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType( "text/html" );
textPane.setEditable(false);
```

After that use HTML editor and proceed your HTML:

```
HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)textPane.getDocument();
HTMLEditorKit editorKit = (HTMLEditorKit)textPane.getEditorKit();
String text = "your HTML here";
editorKit.insertHTML(document, document.getLength(), text, 0, 0, null);
```

Note that this is example. You have to adjust this to your needs.
I think that helps.

Comment: then my html code can be included css code no?

Comment: If you want to add css, I think that can give you an idea. Please, take a look at this link http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-add-style-stylesheet-jeditorpane-example-code.